# Programmatically tagging in Mavericks from an Sandboxed App

Tags: cocoa, osx-mavericks, appstore-sandbox

I am writing to a file in an sandboxed app and later trying to set the tags for it using `-[NSURL setResourceValue:theTags forKey:NSURLTagNamesKey error:&theTaggingError];`. I am not getting any errors (i.e, tags are successfully applied once) but eventually file is kind of replaced and tags are lost. This is only in sandboxed app; if I turn off sandboxing things work fine. In sandboxed mode, if I set tags without writing to the file - again things work fine.

In essence, I am unable to set tags of a file after writing to it. How can I fix it? Any insights?

Sample Code:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
{
    NSWindow *_window;
    NSURL *_saveURL;
    NSSavePanel *_savePanel;
}
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (retain) NSURL *saveURL;
@property (retain) NSSavePanel *savePanel;
- (IBAction)writeAndTag:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)justTag:(id)sender;
@end


@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize saveURL = _saveURL;
@synthesize savePanel = _savePanel;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    self.savePanel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
}

- (IBAction)writeAndTag:(id)sender
{
    [self.savePanel beginSheetModalForWindow:self.window completionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
        self.saveURL = [self.savePanel URL];

        NSString *testString = @"Hello!";
        NSError *error = nil;
        [testString writeToFile:[self.saveURL path] atomically:NO encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
        if(error)
        {
            NSLog(@"Err in saving: %@" ,error);
            error = nil;
        }
        // Tag is lost here
        BOOL success = [self.saveURL setResourceValue:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Test", nil] forKey:NSURLTagNamesKey error:&error];
        NSLog(@"Tagging success: %@", (success)?@"YES":@"NO");
        if(error)
        {
            NSLog(@"Err in tagging: %@" ,error);
        }
    }];
}

- (IBAction)justTag:(id)sender
{
    // Works fine
    [self.saveURL setResourceValue:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Test", nil] forKey:NSURLTagNamesKey error:NULL];
}

@end
```

Comment: Anything appearing in the system logs (`Console.app`)?

Comment: @trojanfoe, Nope.. No logs

Comment: And are you using security-scoped bookmarks to retain access to the documents between app runs?

Comment: @trojanfoe, I am just using SavePanel to get URL. Not explicitly used any security scoping

Comment: So when you say "later" is that within the same run of the app (i.e. it hasn't been terminated between saving and you modifying the tags)?

Comment: It is immediately after saving; later I guess it works. (tags are probably lost due to some atomic writing - file replacement; there is no issue in writing tags, I guess)

Comment: Exactly. Did you try to use NSString writeToURL (instead of writeToPath) and also use it atomically?